# How to delimit a series of values in a string

Tags: python

I have some output that I can spin one of two ways when writing to a text file. The variable I am writing is produced through the concurrent futures module within Python and consists of 200 values at a time. If i write the variable returned directly to file I need to use the "wb" for 'write binary' option in the write statement and I get an output like this:

```
val1
val2
val3
val4
val5
```

If I convert the value to a string and remove some of the special characters that writing to a text file produces when using the "w" option in the write statement I get an output that looks like this:

```
val1 val2 val3 val4 val5
```

That in itself would create a space delimited text file that I could then read into SAS, however in some instances the value of 'val1' etc could be a two word character string or other situations in which their might be a space that is not meant to be a delimiter.

The values above are produced by submitting a url statement of the following format:

```
www.finance.yahoo.com&s=var1+var2+var3+var4+var5&f=metric
```

Is there a way that I can add a delimiter character into the output that I know definitely won't appear in the data elsewhere? I can't use commas either as some of the fields contain them as well.

Thanks

Comment: You need both a delimiter and a quoting character. Take a look at the csv module.

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised if SAS couldn't handle csv quoting.

Comment: @user3045351 Try marking "csv quoting" with your mouse, then press Ctrl+C, open a new tab in your browser and press Ctrl+V on the address bar. (Or the mnemonic your OS uses).

Comment: @user3045351: the rules that produce lines looking like `v1,v2 v3,"v4,v5"` which can be parsed so you can have delimiters within entries.

Comment: "that I know definitely won't appear in the data elsewhere" -- yes, you must encode the data when you serialize it.  The encoding will give it some framing/escape.  Consider JSON, CSV, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of characters that aren't supposed to be used in URLs. You may be tempted to use one of those to delimit your values, BUT - there is really nothing *ensuring* those characters never show up in one of your values.

csv is likely the way to go anyway. The python module has a few optional parameters to tweak the quoting, so you should check first what SAS will accept and then tune the csv writer to that spec.

Answer (score 0):

### Define a csv dialect using the csv module

Here's a basic example, you may need to adjust the parameters of the dialect.

```
import csv
csv.register_dialect('sas', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
with open('myfile', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='sas')
    writer.writerows(someiterable)
```

Comment: ok, i think I get that...i will try it in a bit and see if it works for me. thanks...

Comment: if it works you might want to upvote the answer and mark it as correct.